# Retrieving coordinates from google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

This plunker shows a google map.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BfYggKO8nDolhmpq92dq?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngMap">

<head>
  <title>Simle Map</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Simple Map">
  <meta name="keywords" content="ng-map,AngularJS,center">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]"></ng-map>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to know the coordinates of specific points on the map. If the user right-click on the mouse button on any points on the map, an alert will appear showing the coordinates.

The code uses angularjs and the ng-map module. http://ngmap.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add an event listener and then show the coordinates inside that event like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Simle Map</title>
<meta name="description" content="Simple Map">
<meta name="keywords" content="ng-map,AngularJS,center">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']); 
  app.controller('EventDomListenerController', function($window) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showAlert = function(event, args) {
      $window.alert(event.latLng.lat()+', '+event.latLng.lng());
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="EventDomListenerController as vm">
  <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]" on-click="vm.showAlert()"></ng-map>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NyfXUp2oHE8P6DASy0ng?p=preview)

Comment: I tried hard to understand your code but have difficulties in some parts. I posted a new question it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172031/explanation-of-code-on-google-map